# Select element with jQuery based on the inner content of the previous one?

Tags: jquery, html

To illustrate:

```
<div id="input-content" contenteditable="true">
<p>Some text<p>
<p>Some text<p>
<p><br></p>
<p>Some text<p> <!-- I want to select the p tag after the p tag containing br -->
<p>Some text<p>
```

How can I archive that with jQuery?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`:has()`](http://api.jquery.com/has-selector/) selector

> Selects elements which contain at least one element that matches the specified selector.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
 var text = $('#input-content p:has(br)')//Find p with br tag
   .next('p') //Move to next p
   .text();
 alert(text);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="input-content" contenteditable="true">
    <p>Some text<p>
    <p>Some text<p>
    <p><br></p>
    <p>I want to select the p tag after the p tag containing br </p> 
    <p>Some text<p>
</div>
```

Comment: You can skip the `.next()`at the expense of lisibility by doing `$('#input-content p:has(br) + p')`. +1

Comment: @Karl-AndréGagnon: You are absolutely correct, but `.next()` simple to understand.

Answer (score 0):

Try this : `$('p br').parent().next()`

Comment: You should explain why this code should be tried or why it works.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
$("#input-content").find("p > br").parent().next("p");
```

Answer (score 0):

I'll advise you refactor your HTML and add some structure. Use divs, spans etc. and add class/id attributes.

Selecting text based on a line break is not ideal and you will find your code breaking each time there's a change in the structure of the output text.